# How to create a "Nested ssh tunnel"?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I connect to a linux server over 2 other server:

```
MyPC --(ssh)--> serverA --(ssh)--> serverB --(ssh)--> FinalServer
```

httpd is running on FinalServer, listen on 80
serverA/serverB only accept port 22, sshd service

Is there any way to access FinalServer on myPC like this:

```
myPC> curl http://127.0.0.1:80
Hi , this is FinalServer Httpd Service!!
myPC>
```

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you would only need to tunnel port 80 at every ssh.

So, at every step: `ssh -L80:localhost:80 <next-host>`.

However, you will not be able to tunnel port 80 (and all ports < 1024) without root privileges, so you'll have to use a different port for this.

Comment: You can use ports above 1024 in the intermediary boxes, and point to :80 on MyPC (assuming root privs on it)